# (Done) Can we reopen "How can I deal with troublesome Professional Engineer?"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How can I deal with troublesome Professional Engineer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63205/how-can-i-deal-with-troublesome-professional-engineer)

The question was closed for the "Real questions have real answers" reason.

There were numerous answers to this one, and an employee staging a job actions is something that is common enough that I think this should be reopened.

Comment: Really folks?  this is meta, the down-voters could at least comment here.

Comment: Not the downvoter but for necromancy maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been reopened.